# RXJava persist return value of previous flatMap

Tags: java, rx-java

In RX JAVA(java8), how can I persist value of previous `flatMap` or `map`.

```
public void createAccount(]) {
    JsonObject payload = routingContext.getBodyAsJson();
    socialService.getOAuthToken(payload)
            .flatMap(token -> {
                return getAllAccounts(token);
            })
            .flatMap(accounts -> {
                // Save accounts with TOKENS
            })
            .subscribe(accountID -> {
                  response(accountID);
            );
}
```

So in above code, in second `flatMap` how can I get the `token` from previous `flatMap`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to zip account and token and pass it to the next `Stream` operation.

```
//Note you have to replace T, A with the right type
socialService.getOAuthToken(payload).flatMap(token -> getAllAccounts(token)
        .map(account -> new SimpleImmutableEntry<T, A>(token, account)))
     .flatMap(accounts -> /* accounts.getKey() -> token, accounts.getValue() -> account */)
     .subscribe(accountId -> response(accountId));
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin solution based on the solution by @Flown:

```
socialService.getOAuthToken(payload)
    .flatMap { token -> 
        getAllAccounts(token)
            .map { account -> Pair(token, account) }
     }
     .flatMap { (token, account) -> /* Use values here */ }
     .subscribe { accountId -> response(accountId) }
```

Comment: elegant solution .. thnx